# ¿Cómo realizo un evento una vez un div deseado, obtenga una clase?

Tags: jquery, animación, progressbar

Estoy intentado realizar una animación que consiste en el progreso de unas barras una vez el div que las contiene, aparezca.
La idea es que las barras de progreso empiecen a cargar una vez el div aparezca y no antes...

**Este es el HTML**

```
<div id="skills-graphic" class="module">
<div class="col">
<div class="skill-bar" data-percent="85%">
<h4>HTML5</h4>
<div class="progress-bar"></div>
</div>
<div class="skill-bar" data-percent="79%">
<h4>CSS3</h4>
<div class="progress-bar"></div>
</div>
<div class="skill-bar" data-percent="18%">
<h4>JQuery</h4>
<div class="progress-bar"></div>
</div>
<div class="skill-bar" data-percent="14%">
<h4>PHP</h4>
<div class="progress-bar"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Efecto de animación del DIV**

```
var win = $(window);
var allMods = $(".module");

allMods.each(function(i, el) {
    var el = $(el);
    if(el.visible(true)) { el.addClass("already-visible"); }
});

win.scroll(function(event) {  
    allMods.each(function(i, el) {
        var el = $(el);
        if(el.visible(true)) { el.addClass("come-in"); }
    });
});
```

**Efecto de las barras de progreso**

```
$('#skills-graphic.already-visible .skill-bar').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.progress-bar').animate({ width:$(this).attr('data-percent') }, 3000);
});
```

El problema es que una vez que el div aparece al hacer scroll y este, tras la animación, recibe la clase `already-visible`, las barras no aumentan de tamaño.

*Gracias por la ayuda*

Comment: ¿Estás usando algún plugin?¿Cuál? Deberías crear un [mcve] para que podamos ver el problema concreto

Comment: Podéis mirarlo en la página donde lo estoy subiendo: http://antoniobuenog.com/

Comment: Como bien dije, una vez el div de las barras aparece, no se ejecuta la función del % de su width

Comment: El problema si hacemos eso es que, cuando soluciones el error, ya  no se podrá ver el fallo en ese enlace y esta pregunta dejará de tener utilidad para el resto de usuarios. Toda la información relacionada con la pregunta y el código mínimo con el error, deben estar en la pregunta en sí. Un usuario de SO no debería abandonar el sitio para ver un problema.

Comment: Ok perdona, dame un momento

Comment: Yo veo que ya lo tienes solucionado

Comment: Problema solucionado

Comment: @Antonio puedes responder tus propias preguntas :) [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo a la [revisión 3 de ediciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/49160/3) el OP y el [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49160/c%C3%B3mo-realizo-un-evento-una-vez-un-div-deseado-obtenga-una-clase#comment86668_49160) esta fue su solución:

Acabo de encontrar el error por mi cuenta. Y era básicamente poner un `if` dentro de la función que asignaba la clase `come-in` a los diferentes `div` que quisiese que apareciesen con animación. Si el `div` que aparecía con animación, era el que contenía las barras de progreso, que estas se ejecutaran.

Aquí tenéis el código:

```
var win = $(window);
var allMods = $(".module");

allMods.each(function(i, el) {
    var el = $(el);
    if(el.visible(true)) { el.addClass("already-visible"); }
});

win.scroll(function(event) {  
    allMods.each(function(i, el) {
        var el = $(el);
        if(el.visible(true)) {
            el.addClass("come-in");
            if(el.is("#skills-graphic")){
                $('.skill-bar').each(function(){
                    $(this).find('.progress-bar').animate({ width:$(this).attr('data-percent') }, 3000);
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Siento las molestias